# Exporting Training Data in DialogFlow ES

Tags: dialogflow-es

I can see how I can view training data - particularly unanswered questions is what I need. However, I would like to export this data for someone else (without access to the system) to review. Is there a way I can export training data to any format?

Comment: The formats you can export data to are JSON or CSV, here is where you can find this data and how you can export it[1].
[1]https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-export#where

Comment: Thank you. That link references entities, but not training data. I was able to capture the json from the UI in Chrome behind the scenes for now.